# Removing a substring from a column in a text file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a shell script:

```
a ab.mi
3 jm.mi
56 uh.mi
```

I want to remove .mi from the 2nd column and make it like:

```
a ab
3 jm
56 uh
```

How can I do this with shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'gsub("\.mi", "", $2)1' inputfile
```

This would remove `.mi` from the second column.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to remove the string `.mi` then a simple `sed` substitution will do:

```
$ sed 's/[.]mi//' file
a ab
3 jm
56 uh
```

If you really want to restrict to the second column `awk` is better choice but with `sed` you could do:

```
$ sed -r 's/(\S+\s+\S+)[.]mi/\1/' file
a ab
3 jm
56 uh
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl One-Liner:

```
perl -pe -i.bak 's/\.mi$//i' file
```